# http access to crossdomain.xml within flash

Tags: flash, https, crossdomain.xml

I have an **html** hosted on Amazon which basically has an **embedded flash object** on it. I am accessing this html through https protocol and the common "**Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely**" alert on IE is being displayed. This problem happens also when hitting the swf file directly using an url with https protocol.

I know it is because "somehow" inside the swf file there is an non-secure HTTP access to the external file "**crossdomain.xml**" but the point is that I am not able to modify the swf movie. Is there any way to programmatically solve this security issue (avoid the error message) without modifying the swf file neither any configuration on my IE browser?

If it is not how can I remove the references to this file? I decompiled the swf file and did not find any explicit reference within the ActionScript code. Anyway this file is currently being "hosted" on an external server and does not exist anymore (404 Not Found error is being returned).

Any help will be more than appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Why does it try to hit crossdomain.xml? Which cross-domain resource is the .swf file trying to hit? Seems somewhat unlikely that you can solve this without access to the source of the swf.

Comment: right ... I read that is some standard file that keeps policy information but I cannot edit the swf so I was wondering about other ways to prevent the swf from calling that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to access a resource in another domain from Flash, flash will initially make a request to crossdomain.xml on the same domain. This means that your swf is attempting to access a file over http on a different domain. You can't fix this without editing the swf.